# Download latest 4.2 eclipse build. Is it broken?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno

I am looking for the latest eclipse build specifically for **4.2**.
In [this](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) downloads page the latest is the `4.2 Maintenance Build` but when I go to the download area following this link the page is I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDKzb.png):

[image]

Why is the status with red X? Is the build broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maintenance builds are produced periodically to incorporate fixes into an existing release. They are typically built from tagged plug-in and feature pojects in a maintenance branch of the Git repository (i.e. R3_7_maintenance). Maintenance builds are promoted to a minor or service release (i.e. R3.7 or R3.7.1) after development teams have deemed one to be stable following one or more test-fix pass cycles.

Maintenance builds don't have to be stable. Go for release builds of the current and stable builds of the next version. Integration builds *should* be stable too - but actually I see some test failures there too.

Comment: So the image actually shows that there are failures in **all** areas?That is what the red X shows?

Comment: A red cross shows that at least one test failed. Simply click on the mark to see the test results.

Answer (score 0):

One line above your download link is a [description of the different kinds of builds](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/build_types.html), which you should read to understand that a maintenance build is not your best option.